# Canceling a task

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task, task-parallel-library

I have a task which i need to cancel if the wait time is over. For instance

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
  Thread.Sleep(5000) // some long running task
  "do something"
});
Task.WaitAll(new[] {t}, 1000);
```

But it seems the task still keeps working. I tried using CancellationTokenSource but that didnt seem to work as well.

I confirmed this using the following snippet

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("Still working");
            }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            Task.WaitAll(new[] {t}, 1000);

            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Console displays "Still working". I thought the task would have been cancelled.

I am sure I am missing something. What am i missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Cancellation tokens don't magically cancel anything. They just *allow* you to check for cancellation in a standardized way, e.g. via [`ThrowIfCancellationRequested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested.aspx).

So typically you'd have some task which needs to perform a lot of work. It periodically calls `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`, and then any code which needs to cancel the task will call [`Cancel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel.aspx) on the `CancellationTokenSource` when it needs to. The task will throw when it next checks for cancellation, and all will be well.

It sounds like you're looking for a non-cooperative cancellation - and that would be dangerous, for exactly the same reasons that the normal `Thread.Abort` is dangerous. It's cleaner to let the task pick the points at which it will allow itself to be cancelled.